# Short Story of a robot walking endlessly as the ages go by ...Maybe it is a huge ship or a giant earth , don't remember that part

Tags: story-identification

There is reference to this age being in millions of years but the robot doesn't know. It is in english . I think the robot is internally powered by a black hole or something . It goes mostly unnoticed by the humans until they trap him and are scared of him . The trapper is maybe a lady chief and she says that his age is over 700 million years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This has very few details; you don't even say if it's a short story or a cartoon.  Please [edit] this to add everything else you can think of; when you saw/read this, where, what language, etc.

Comment: I have added some more details .

Comment: @StackLover do you know where you read it, if it was in it's own book or a larger collection? What year was it released or that you read it

Comment: I think it was part of a larger collection and was pre-2000s atleast .

Comment: Could be this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203551/sci-fi-book-about-a-shape-shifting-machine-wandering-the-surface-of-a-planet-siz/203553?r=SearchResults#203553

Comment: @Baronet_Canid Thanks , that is it !  'Alone' by robert reed

Comment: @Baronet_Canid Please post an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You're thinking of "Alone" a by Robert Reed. It is a short story in the Greatship series. There is a similar answer here: [Sci-fi book about a shape shifting machine wandering the surface of a planet sized space ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203551/sci-fi-book-about-a-shape-shifting-machine-wandering-the-surface-of-a-planet-siz/203553?r=SearchResults#203553)